# Acessing data on `inst/extdata` from Rcpp Catch tests

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, testthat, catch-unit-test

I am trying to access a data file on a `inst/extdata` file from a Rcpp Catch2 test. The file tree looks like this:

```
├── inst
│   └── extdata
│       └── data-sample
├── R
│   ├── catch-routine-registration.R
│   └── RcppExports.R
├── src
    ├── mycode.cpp
    ├── RcppExports.cpp
    ├── Package_types.h
    ├── test-example.cpp
    └── test-runner.cpp
```

Which would be similar from what you'd get from a new package skeleton using devtools, I believe. Now, I can access this `data-sample` file from a testthat test pretty easily like this:

```
system.file(
    "extdata", "data-sample", package = "Package", mustWork = TRUE
)
```

And use it as needed. I am aware that this uses the global path from the installed package at this point, however I can't find a way to pass this value to my c++ tests. I am currently using a hardcoded path, but that obviously only works on my machine.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
const std::string DATAFILE = "/my/package/inst/extdata/data-sample";
```

Since this is a function for reading files I really can't embed this in any way, but I still want to know: how to pass R data to the Rcpp/Catch tests?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to get the return value of the R function call `system.file("extdata", "data-sample", package = "Package", mustWork = TRUE)` from C++?

Comment: @duckmayr Yes, that'd solve my problem, however I need to pass that to C++ that is being called by R. Since this is a test file, it's not a single function for me to pass a `Function` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `system.file()` path by calling the R function from C++, even if it's not an exported C++ function (this is how I have interpreted your query following comments to the post and to Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer). Consider the following C++ code in `print_extdata.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

Rcpp::StringVector get_extdata(){
    Rcpp::Environment base("package:base");
    Rcpp::Function sys_file = base["system.file"];
    Rcpp::StringVector res = sys_file("extdata", "2012.csv",
                                      Rcpp::_["package"] = "testdat");
    return res;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_extdata() {
    Rcpp::StringVector path = get_extdata();
    Rcpp::Rcout << path;
}
```

Then called from R:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("print_extdata.cpp")
> print_extdata()
"/home/duckmayr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/testdat/extdata/2012.csv"
```

Comment: Accepted because it was exactly what I needed, thank you!
I've found out that the package isn't registered at this time on the testing sides, so while it works in a normal R session/in the package use, I can't seem to find out why it can't find the package at testing time... I'll look more into it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a hard coded path. Try try to figure out if you need at

- *package built time* and then it would be `../inst/extdata/data-sample/foo.csv`, or
- once *installed* in which case it is standard `system.file("extdata/foo.csv", package="yourpackage")`

That is a bit of issue for R packages in general -- but even when your do `R CMD check` it actually *installs the package first* so you are in the second case.

Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, I want exactly that second case. However, how can I pass that to the C++ tests? I don't think that my question left this clear, but this is the main issue that I'm having. I can test with the second case in R tests as I want, but not if I want to do a similar test in Rcpp, which I can't (or better, don't want to) expose to R. In summary: I want to know how to pass that system.file path after it has been installed to the Catch tests.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this as another answer, as I only got to it from Dirk's and duckmayr's answers.

I found out that the package at the Rcpp testing time hadn't been loaded yet, and so duckmayr's answer didn't work out of the box. However, after some fiddling, I found out that his code when called only with the `package` option would output the current project path, and so I found out that at that point the package would be loaded, however with the path from the project repository.

This is indeed a bit confusing, as the tests that use R work with the R installation folder as expected (eg. `/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/`). I need to dig deeper to see why this is so.

In the end, I went with this function to be able to get the path in the tests:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>

std::string get_datapath_fromR(std::string filename, std::string packageName)
{
    Rcpp::Environment base("package:base");
    Rcpp::Function sys_file = base["system.file"];
    // "inst" field is necessary at this point
    Rcpp::StringVector file_path_sv = sys_file(
        "inst", "extdata", filename,
        Rcpp::_["package"] = packageName,
        Rcpp::_["mustWork"] = true
    );
    std::string file_path = Rcpp::as<std::string>(file_path_sv);
    return file_path;
}
```

And I can call it on a test like this:

```
...
std::string datafile = get_datapath_fromR("data-sample", "package");        
...
```

And get this as a result: `/home/user/path/to/package/folder/packageName/inst/extdata/data-sample`